# c# Master template for a menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a mvc web app that has a Master.cshtml page for elements that will be universally found on my website.

I am having an issue with the menu in the header, which has class="active" for various list elements for menu items. For example, If you are on the home page, then the home page menu item is highlighted; if you are on the contact us page, then the contact us page menu item is highlighted.

Because of the dynamic nature of the menu, I could not include it in the Master.cshtml page because the class"active" would not be dynamic, but rather static.

Is there a way to place the majority of the menu in the Master template page? The website is growing quite large, and it is quite tedious to add menu items (since the change would need to be reflected in almost 150 pages of the website, since the menu is on each individual page).

Comment: Your layout page should include `@{ Html.RenderAction(...); }` that calls a `ChildActionOnly` method that returns a partial view of your menu. In that code you can check the current controller and action method and conditionally set the appropriate menu item with `class="active"`

Comment: You have not given any code or context, so impossible to add an answer, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692877/css-class-wont-be-applied-to-a-helper-extension-with-a-partial-view/29693675#29693675) should give you a hint